# How Do Validators Differentiate Between '&' and '&amp'?

Tags: validation, parsing, ascii

Knowing that `&amp;` is the html entity value of & - how do validators like w3c know this? Even when I look at my source code it's already been parsed into the correct value.

Comment: That's not an ascii value, that's an html entity.

Comment: @Co_42 I guess I don't know the difference between the two >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise -- as Co_42 noted, `&amp;` is not the "ASCII value" of `'&'`. It's a HTML [character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) representing the character `'&'`. The ASCII value of `'&'` is `38` (or `0x26`).

Your source code almost certainly consists of ASCII or Unicode text files. Those don't use HTML entities. If you have a string with an ampersand stored in the source code, it'll probably be stored with a bare `"&"`. If there's a string literal somewhere containing actual HTML data, it may contain `"&amp;"`.

When you use some sort of tool or function to convert strings to text ready to put into for an HTML or XML document, any `"&"` will be (should be!) converted into `"&amp;"`.

When a program that reads HTML documents encounters an ASCII `"&"`, it can assume that that's the beginning of a HTML character reference. This is okay because *all* ampersands in the actual text should have been converted into `"&amp;"`.

As a somewhat perverse example, if you open your source code in a word processor and save it as an HTML document, you'll find that in the actual file, `"&"` has been converted into `"&amp;"` (and `"&amp;"` has been converted into `"&amp;amp;"`). If you then *open* that document in a browser, you'll find that the ampersands are displayed the same way they are when you view your source code in a text editor. The encoding step that happened when you saved the HTML document corresponds to the decoding step that happens when the browser displays it.

If you put something like `"Fish & chips"` directly into an actual HTML document, your HTML document will be invalid. Complicating the matter is the fact that programs such as browsers tend to try to *recover* from errors in document and display the documents anyway. As such, your browser may still display `"Fish & chips"` on the screen when you open your invalid document. However, a program such as the W3C validator, which is specifically meant to discover errors in HTML documents, will notify you that your document is invalid.